# Error occurs when fitting time series data in GARCH model using rugarch package

Tags: r, frequency, bitcoin

I want to analyze the GARCH effect on Bitcoin daily returns from 2015 to 2018 using rugarch package. I imported the data from a csv file using zoo package, and the header of my data (BTC_Return) looks like this:

```
2015-01-02   2015-01-03   2015-01-04   2015-01-05   2015-01-06   2015-01-07 
 0.001015636 -0.093303963 -0.081262425  0.037516428  0.026674925  0.031626936
```

And when I tried to fit the data in GARCH(1,1) model, this error occurred under Weighted ARCH LM Tests section: "Error in if (frequency > 1 && abs(frequency - round(frequency)) < ts.eps) frequency <- round(frequency) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed". Here is the code that I used:

```
> library(zoo)
> BTC_Return <- read.zoo('BTC_Data.csv', header = TRUE, sep = ",", index.column = 1, format = "%Y/%m/%d")
> class(BTC_Return)
> BTC_Return_garch11_spec <- ugarchspec(variance.model = list(garchOrder = c(1,1)), mean.model = list(armaOrder = c(0,0)))
> BTC_Return_garch11_fit <- ugarchfit(spec = BTC_Return_garch11_spec, data = BTC_Return)
> BTC_Return_garch11_fit

*---------------------------------*
*          GARCH Model Fit        *
*---------------------------------*

Conditional Variance Dynamics   
-----------------------------------
GARCH Model : sGARCH(1,1)
Mean Model  : ARFIMA(0,0,0)
Distribution    : norm 

Optimal Parameters
------------------------------------
        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.001887    0.000717   2.6322 0.008484
omega   0.000024    0.000007   3.3136 0.000921
alpha1  0.142601    0.019727   7.2289 0.000000
beta1   0.856399    0.018160  47.1585 0.000000

Robust Standard Errors:
        Estimate  Std. Error  t value Pr(>|t|)
mu      0.001887    0.000766   2.4628 0.013786
omega   0.000024    0.000017   1.3863 0.165640
alpha1  0.142601    0.041243   3.4576 0.000545
beta1   0.856399    0.041346  20.7129 0.000000

LogLikelihood : 2685.051 

Information Criteria
------------------------------------

Akaike       -3.9254
Bayes        -3.9101
Shibata      -3.9254
Hannan-Quinn -3.9197

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                      5.321 0.02107
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][2]     5.997 0.02203
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]     7.863 0.03187
d.o.f=0
H0 : No serial correlation

Weighted Ljung-Box Test on Standardized Squared Residuals
------------------------------------
                        statistic p-value
Lag[1]                      5.192 0.02269
Lag[2*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][5]     7.363 0.04230
Lag[4*(p+q)+(p+q)-1][9]     8.637 0.09635
d.o.f=2

Weighted ARCH LM Tests
------------------------------------
Error in if (frequency > 1 && abs(frequency - round(frequency)) < ts.eps) frequency <- round(frequency) : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

Can anyone help me fix this problem? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately my post won't help you but maybe those searching for related questions, like I did.

I had a similar problem where estimating the gjr-garch model caused the `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`-error for the whole estimation. When searching for a solution I came upon your post.

My problem was caused by missing values (solved with a `omit.na()`) and using a tibble instead of numeric values (solved with a `as.numeric(unlist())`).